# Click on RUN button in UFT - nothing happens

Tags: hp-uft

I am trying to launch IE using UFT. Wrote the script for the same and click on RUN button nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to help you.
Did you set the run configuration to run on open browser or launch browser?
Or did you write the launch from the script it else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue after I ran a Windows Update on my laptop
Clicking Run in UFT and nothing happens
Usually, it was starting executing my driver script

Answer (score 0):

This run issue i noticed for UFT 14.53 with windows 10 version 20H2. You need to apply UFT 14.53 patch 4 to resolve this issue according to the UFT 14.53 Product Availability Matrix

https://admhelp.microfocus.com/documents/uft/UFT_14.xx_PAM.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.